# Select all records of a datatable with duplicate values

Tags: c#, linq

How do we select all the record of particular year (e.g. 2014) from a datatable where one of the column value(here 2014) is repeated on multiple rows of 
table using linq or any other method in C#.

This is the datatable:

[image: datatable]

Comment: I am trying to retriving all the duplicated records but whatever you are doing will remove duplicate and give filtered data... But help me anyway..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to retrieve all the records lies on the Year 2014, use following linq query,IT will check your data column has data or not, I am sure it will works..

```
        //selecting all the records of 2014
        IEnumerable<DataRow> dtrow = default(IEnumerable<DataRow>);
        dtrow = yourtable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<Int64>("year") == Convert.ToInt64("2014"));
        if (dtrow.Count() > 0)
        {
            dataTbl = dtrow.CopyToDataTable(); //dataTbl is the DataTable
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while since I've worked with `DataTables` but I think this should do it.

To select rows where the year is duplicated across more than one row:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["Year"]).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
```

To select only the rows for a particular year:

```
dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x["Year"] == "2014");
```

Where `dt` is your `System.Data.DataTable`.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answers, But I want to retrieve the records of only 2014 or 2015 and so on.

Comment: Hopefully my edit is a little more accurate to what you're wanting?

Comment: Thank you very much for your both answers Jonz.

Comment: How to get the result as a datatable again ?

Comment: @GuidoG Something like `ds.Tables[0]` where `ds` is your `DataSet`.

Comment: @Shelby115 How is this comment answering my question ?

Comment: @GuidoG You asked how to get the result as a DataTable. The original question nor your question provide any context beyond that, so the only possible answer without additional details or context is what I responded with. Honestly, I hadn't noticed it was a comment from 2019, so we can just disregard my response.

Comment: @Shelby115 Neither in the question, nor in the answer, nor in my comment there is any mention of a dataset, that is why I wondered how your comment has any relation to any of them. But you are right, lets disregard this old post

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it in database since it is faster than C#. DB can have index but C# does not have.

```
select *, count(1) as totalCount
group by year
having totalCount > 1
```