# How to get the result of a `linq` back to a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, linq, datatable

How to get the result of a `linq` back to a DataTable ?

I am trying the solution from this thread :
[Select all records of a datatable with duplicate values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36192598/select-all-records-of-a-datatable-with-duplicate-values)

But it fails to compile for me.

This is my code

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> dtrow = default(IEnumerable<DataRow>);
dtrow = dtTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["MerkTypeID"]).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
using (DataTable table = dtrow.CopyToDataTable())
{

}
```

but VS gives this error

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<object, System.Data.DataRow>>` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Data.DataRow>`. An
>   explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I also tried it like this

```
var dtrow = dtTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["MerkTypeID"]).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
using (DataTable table = dtrow.CopyToDataTable())
{

}
```

but now I get this error

> Error CS0311  The type `System.Linq.IGrouping<object, System.Data.DataRow>` cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the
>   generic type or method
>   `DataTableExtensions.CopyToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`. There is no
>   implicit reference conversion from `System.Linq.IGrouping<object, System.Data.DataRow>` to `System.Data.DataRow`.

So how to do this ? And why does it seem to work in the link where I found this code ?

**EDIT**
I tried this suggestion of henri :

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> dtrow = default(IEnumerable<DataRow>);
dtrow = (IEnumerable<DataRow>)gttDataTableOpdrachtCar.Table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["MerkTypeID"]).Where(x => x.Count() > 1);
using (DataTable table = dtrow.CopyToDataTable())
```

this compiles, but at runtime i get this error :

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereEnumerableIterator`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.Object,System.Data.DataRow]]'
>   to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Data.DataRow]'.

Comment: Because you do a `GroupBy` it creates grouped sets of datarows. You either have to flatten it or select a single element for it to work.

Comment: For the first example, it compiles if you cast it via `(IEnumerable<DataRow>) dtTable.AsEnumerable()...`

Comment: GroupBy gets a 2-D array [group][DataRow[]].  An array of datarows[] you can use CopyToDataTable.  So I think this will work : dtrow.SelectMany(x => x).CopyToDataTable()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
var result = dtTable.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => x["MerkTypeID"])
    .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
    .SelectMany(x => x.ToList())
    .CopyToDataTable();
```

If you group the rows by `MerkTypeID`, it returns all the rows of the groups having more than one member.

Answer (score 0):

You have a type mismatch. That's what a compiler is telling you. When you execute a .GroupBy clasue, it creates a collection of groups, and as far as I can tell, you require flat collection of DataRows.

You need to get rid of .GroupBy clasuse, or transform your collection of groups into a flat list. For now you have a collection of groups, one for each "MerkTypeID", and each group contains all the records with that MerkTypeID value.